# How to refer to inherited attributes in Hibernate JPA @NamedEntityGraph?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1

I've the following mapping in my project:

```
@Embeddable
class LineItem {
    ...
}

@Entity
abstract class Invoice {
    ...
    @ElementCollection @OrderColumn @NotEmpty
    List<LineItem> lineItems = []
    ...
}

@Entity
class PurchaseInvoice extends Invoice {
    ...
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    Payment payment
    ...
}

@Entity
class Payment {
    ...
    @ElementCollection @OrderColumn
    List<PaymentTerm> paymentTerms = []
    ...
}

@Embeddable
class PaymentTerm {
    ...
}
```

All collection assosications are lazy by default.  My goal is to create an entity graph that can be used to eagerly load `PurchaseInvoice.lineItems` and `PurchaseInvoice.payment.paymentTerms`.

If I define the following entity graph:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name='PurchaseInvoiceWithDetail', attributeNodes = [
     @NamedAttributeNode(value='payment', subgraph='payment'),
     @NamedAttributeNode(value='lineItems')
], subgraphs = [
     @NamedSubgraph(name='payment', type=Payment, attributeNodes = [
         @NamedAttributeNode(value='paymentTerms')
     ])
])
@Entity
class PurchaseInvoice extends Invoice
```

I got the following **Unable to build entity manager factory** error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the given name [lineItems] on this ManagedType [PurchaseInvoice]
```

What is the proper way to refer to an attribute in superclass (or subclasses) in JPA 2.1 entity graph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not supported as of hibernate-entitymanager 4.3.4.  This is what I found so far:

1. `@NamedAttributeNode` **can't** be used to refer to superclass' attributes.
2. `includeAllAttributes=true` will include all attributes including superclass' attributes.
3. `@NamedAttributeNode` in subgraph can refer to superclass' attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a simple syntax- problem in the definition of the graph? In my opinion the definition does not contain square brackets.
I've tested your code and it was ok.

See:[Developerblog](http://hantsy.blogspot.de/2013/12/jpa-21-entity-graph.html)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So the code is okay. What is the JPA provider you used in the test? I can't make this work in hibernate-entitymanager 4.3.4.Final.  The square brackets is Groovy syntax, it should be compatible with Java.

Comment: I used the hibernate provider. And the Version was 4.3.0. Strange. I looked at many books. Should be ok

Comment: Did you define `@NamedAttributeNode` for an attribute that is located in superclass?  It seems that Hibernate can't find `lineItems` which is not declared in `PurchaseInvoice` but in its parent class, `Invoice`.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9080), this is a Hibernate bug and claimed to be fixed in version 4.3.6

Comment: The issue is resolved when I used version 4.3.10.Final